# Can't get required response using json parameters within get requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get json response from this [webpage](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/instagood/) using the following approach but this is what I get `{"message": "Must provide valid one of: query_id, query_hash", "status": "fail"}`. I tried to print the response url, as in `r.url` in the second script to see if it matches the one I tried to send but I found it different in structure.

If I use the url directly (taken from dev tools) within requests, I get required content:

```
import json
import requests

check_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=7dabc71d3e758b1ec19ffb85639e427b&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22%3A%22instagood%22%2C%22first%22%3A2%2C%22after%22%3A%22QVFDa3djMUFwM1BkRWJNTlEzRmxBYkRGdFBDVzViU2JoNVZPbWNQSmNCTE1HNDlhYWdsdi1EcE5ickhvYjhRWUhqUDhIcXE3YTE4M1JMbmdVN0lMSXM3ZA%3D%3D%22%7D'
r = requests.get(check_url)
print(r.json())
```

But, I can't make it work:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/instagood/'
query_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?'

payload = {
    "query_hash": "7dabc71d3e758b1ec19ffb85639e427b",
    "variables": {"tag_name":"instagood","first":"2","after":"QVFDa3djMUFwM1BkRWJNTlEzRmxBYkRGdFBDVzViU2JoNVZPbWNQSmNCTE1HNDlhYWdsdi1EcE5ickhvYjhRWUhqUDhIcXE3YTE4M1JMbmdVN0lMSXM3ZA=="}
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(query_url,params=json.dumps(payload))
    print(r.content)
```

***How can I make the above script work?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is connected to how you encode the params.
From the `check_url` in your first example we can see:

```
?query_hash=7dabc71d3e758b1ec19ffb85639e427b&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22%3A%22...
```

This URL has 2 params:

1. `query_hash` - string
2. `variables` - looks like a URL encoded string, judging by the escape values (`%7B%22`).

As you have correctly identified, `%7B%22` corresponds to `{"`. In other words, the second parameter is a url-escaped JSON string.

From this we can get a clue about the new solution:

```py
query_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?'

variables = {"tag_name": "instagood", "first": "2",
             "after": "QVFDa3djMUFwM1BkRWJNTlEzRmxBYkRGdFBDVzViU2JoNVZPbWNQSmNCTE1HNDlhYWdsdi1EcE5ickhvYjhRWUhqUDhIcXE3YTE4M1JMbmdVN0lMSXM3ZA=="}
payload = {
    "query_hash": "7dabc71d3e758b1ec19ffb85639e427b",
    "variables": json.dumps(variables)
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' + \
                              'Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(query_url, params=payload)
    print(r.content)
```

As you can see, the `params` passed to the `requests.get` method is a dict with two keys. This will get translated into `?query_hash=value1&variables=value2`.

To get the correct value for `variables`, we just dump the JSON to string. The requests library will take care of URL-escaping all the characters like `{` and `"` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

While running your code, the URL that forms after api call contains unnecessary escape characters. This is what screwing up the API call.

[image: here]
It is not suggested to send data payload while using `get`. A quick solution to this could be using `post` request instead. It worked fine!

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/instagood/'
query_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?'

payload = {
    "query_hash": "7dabc71d3e758b1ec19ffb85639e427b",
    "variables": {"tag_name":"instagood","first":"2","after":"QVFDa3djMUFwM1BkRWJNTlEzRmxBYkRGdFBDVzViU2JoNVZPbWNQSmNCTE1HNDlhYWdsdi1EcE5ickhvYjhRWUhqUDhIcXE3YTE4M1JMbmdVN0lMSXM3ZA=="}
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.post(query_url,params=json.dumps(payload))
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: Note that url parameters are not considered request body, so we're free to use GET.

Comment: Your suggested script fetches the wrong content. Btw, you should use `data` instead of `params` while using within post requests.